# Video URL streams with multiple audio and text tracks/streams?

Tags: audio, video, video-streaming, audio-streaming, adaptive-bitrate

I am testing capability to switch between different audio or text tracks in a given stream (adaptive stream like HLS/Smooth/Dash). Could someone please provide sample video URLs with multiple audio tracks (Dolby, Stereo, DTS), audio language tracks (english, spanish, french) and text tracks (ex: subtitles in different languages)?

If not, is there a recommended tool to be able to combine audio or text tracks to a video file?

Answer (score 2):

This is old question but the answer may help someone coming here.
You can check **yamb** for mixing videos and getting output in mp4 format:

https://www.videohelp.com/software/YAMB

If you want to get output in mkv,you can try mkvToolNix:

https://www.videohelp.com/software/MKVToolNix

Also, if you want to try ffmpeg,check(I haven't tested this):

https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-May/015191.html